# Does eclipse have mysql jdbc driver preinstalled in it?

Tags: java, eclipse

well i use netbeans so i am new to eclipse .Does eclipse have mysql jdbc driver preinstalled in it or do we have to download it?Also how am i suppose to see list of libraries available in eclipse IDE

Comment: _Does eclipse have mysql jdbc driver preinstalled in it_ no it doesn't. You need to add jar file to build path

Comment: http://www.sqlexplorer.org/drivers.php And next time before asking question here ask for help to your [friend](http://google.com) first.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do. Right now this question doesn't make any sense

Comment: @PLB thank you forth enlightment!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse does not exist Mysql jdbc lib. You must download it and add build path in your project.

You can find related lib link below:

http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/MySQL-Connector-J.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is IDE   , it consists of jar as a support for most of frameworks or databases , you can download the jar yourself and adding in your build path or use eclipse library to add it.

[here is how to add mysql jar into eclipse plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Create_and_Export_MySQL_JDBC_driver_bundle)

you will have to first download the jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector.jar.zip)

Regards
Anshul